# mongo secondary has no queries after recovery

Tags: mongodb

I have a test case, a sharding cluster with 1 shard.

The shard is rs, which has 1 primary and 2 secondaries.

My application uses `secondaryPreferred` policy, at first the queries balanced over two secondaries. Then I stop 1 secondary `10.160.243.22` to simulate fault, and then reboot it, the status is ok:

```
rs10032:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs10032",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:21:07Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.160.243.22:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 2211,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1417771218, 3),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:20:18Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:21:05Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:21:07Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing to: 10.160.188.52:27017",
            "syncingTo" : "10.160.188.52:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.160.188.52:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 2211,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1417771218, 3),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:20:18Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1417770837, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:13:57Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.160.189.52:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 2209,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1417771218, 3),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:20:18Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:21:07Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-12-05T09:21:06Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "10.160.188.52:27017"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but all queries go to another secondary `10.160.188.52`, and `10.160.243.22` is idle

Why the queries not balanced to two secondaries after recovery and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application uses some kind of driver(I don't know exact technology stack you are using) to connect to MongoDb. Your driver could remember(cache) replica set status or connections for some period of time. So, there is no guarantee that secondary node will be available immediately after a recovery.

Comment: My application uses pymongo. And after 1 hour the load do not balance to the recovered secondary. And even after restarting application it didn't turn better.